# Query for a month works faster then for a week

Tags: mysql, index

I have strange situation when query for a month works faster then for a week:

There is a request for a month (`2016-06-01 - 2016-07-08`) that works quickly and uses proper index:

```
SELECT  `t1`.* FROM `t1` 
  INNER JOIN `t2` ON `t2`.`t1_id` = `t1`.`id` 
  WHERE
   `t1`.`type` IN ... AND 
   `t1`.`site_id` = ... AND 
   (t1.created_at >= '2016-06-01 07:00:00') AND 
   (t1.created_at <= '2016-07-08 06:59:59')  
   ORDER BY `t1`.`id` DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0;
```

returns 48 rows in 85ms

it uses `INDEX: site_id, type, created_at, subtotal`

The same request for a week (`2016-07-01 - 2016-07-08` or `2016-06-01 - 2016-06-08`) work in 1000 times slower and does not use index

returns 7 rows in 420 sec
returns 13 rows in 420 sec

Table has ~170M records

- MySQL 5.6.23
- `analyze table t1, t2` has not fixed the issue
- `USE INDEX(...)` solves the issue, but it's not a solution for me, I'can't manage indexes manually instead of MySQL
- if remove `LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0` it works fast, but I need it for pagination
- `ORDER BY t1.created_at` works faster, but not enough - 1-10 sec. It also uses wrong index

Is there any solutions?

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subtotal` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Update 2:**

There is `explain` for a week (slow query):

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_t1_on_site_id_and_c1_and_type_and_c2,index_t1_on_created_at_and_site_id,index_t1_on_type,index_t1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_subtotal,index_t1_on_site_and_type_and_c3_and_created_at
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 8991557
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: i1,i2
          key: i1
      key_len: 4
          ref: production.t1.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
```

There is `explain` for a month (fast query):

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_t1_on_site_id_and_c1_and_type_and_c2,index_t1_on_created_at_and_site_id,index_t1_on_type,index_t1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_subtotal,index_t1_on_site_and_type_and_c3_and_created_at
          key: index_t1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_subtotal
      key_len: 88
          ref: NULL
         rows: 7709
        Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: i1,i2
          key: i1
      key_len: 4
          ref: production.t1.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
```

Comment: is `t1.created_at` column a date or timestamp data type? if it is a char or varchar2 field, then that could be confusing the optimizer.

Comment: `t1.created_at` is datetime

Comment: Why is the join to `t2` needed?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Because of business logic: we need to get just that records from `t1` that have associated record in `t2`.

Comment: All right then. But with the current query, if a row in t1 is associated with 2 or more rows in t2, you'll get in the result this row from t2 multiple (2 or more) times accordingly. Do you want that?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There is one-to-one relation: one record from `t1` has 0 or one record in `t2`.

Comment: @Alexey can you please add the EXPLAINs for both cases?

Comment: @Alexey index `(site_id, created_at, type)` might work better (only one range scan can be used efficiently and `IN` is a range scan too). Or maybe just `ORDER BY t1.id + 1` to disable the `order by .. limit` optimization if it is making troubles.

Comment: @jkavalik added `explain` to the topic, see `UPDATE 2` secion

Comment: @jkavalik your suggestion about `ORDER BY t1.id + 1` works. Magic! Can you explain why. It's very sad that I have to hack ORM to make request faster, is there any way to teach MySQL work proper :) ?

Comment: @Alexey there is an "optimization" for cases when you only get first N rows and optimizer decides to go over the PRIMARY key expecting to find N matching rows fast but being wrong and searching much more. The `id + 1` (or `+ 0`, but for ORDER BY it behaves the same) is just a trick to disallow that and confirm it as a cause. There may be much better index possible which won't need such hacks, maybe `(site_id, id, created_at, type)` might work well, removing filesort and utilizing `Using index condition` in both cases but its effectivity depends on your data distribution so you need to test.

Answer (score 2):

(Some of this is redundant, but I will spell it out anyway.)

I think 5.6.23, with MRR, is smart enough to use all 3 columns of `INDEX(site_id, type, created_at)` in that order.  (Older versions would not work as well.)

If you are using a 'range' of `created_at` values, nothing after that column will be used in optimization.  (Unless it is a 'covering' index.)

Instead of using `OFFSET`, "remember where you left off":  [pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/doc.php/pagination).

With 170M rows, you should consider tightening up the datatypes wherever possible.  For example, can `type` changed to a 1-byte `ENUM` or normalized to a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte) instead of `VARCHAR(25)`?  `subtotal` decimal(25,2) takes 11 bytes.  If you don't need the precision of `DECIMAL`, consider an 8-byte `DOUBLE`.  Are there more than 16M sites?  If not, consider a 3-byte `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` instead of a 4-byte `INT SIGNED`.  Etc.

In place of `USE INDEX..` this might be safer: `IGNORE INDEX(PRIMARY)`.

Comment: 5.6.23 is smart and uses right index most time, but sometime it does and it strange. I found that request works properly in MySQL 5.7.11, I will update DB soon

Comment: `IGNORE INDEX(PRIMARY)` - works. Thanks for one more hack :)

Comment: I tried to minimize rows length (VARCHAR -> ENUM), but I haven't got viewable performance increase on test server, so I can't push it on production without good reason

Comment: When the data becomes bigger than the buffer_pool, performance is likely to decline visibly.  (Until then, shrinking datatypes is unlikely to show much difference.)